# CUDA Thrust reduction by key with a tuple key

Tags: cuda, thrust

I've two vectors, and after creating a `tuple` (with `zip_iterator`) I would order them with `sort_by_key` and then apply `reduce_by_key`.

But the reduction by key doesn't work well since it creates an incorrect vector counter. May someone help me? Here is my relevant code snippet.

```
...
typedef thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator IntIterator;
typedef thrust::tuple<IntIterator, IntIterator> IteratorTuple;
typedef thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> ZipIterator;
typedef  thrust::tuple<int, int> tupla; 
...
thrust::device_vector <int> documenti(n);
thrust::device_vector <int> strip(n);
...
ZipIterator bufferBegin (thrust::make_tuple(documenti.begin(),strip.begin()));
ZipIterator bufferEnd (thrust::make_tuple(documenti.end(),strip.end()));

...
thrust::sort_by_key(bufferBegin,bufferEnd, counter.begin());

thrust::device_vector <tupla> example(n);

thrust::reduce_by_key(bufferBegin,bufferEnd, counter.begin(), example.begin(), counter.begin());

thrust::sort_by_key(counter.begin(), counter.begin()+n, example.begin(),thrust::greater <int>());
```

Comment: If you are sorting by key, you need *three* vectors, two to make the tuple and one holding the key to perform the ordering.

Comment: It's not a sorting problem but a reduce problem. when I make a reduce_by_key it generates a wrong result vector. According to what you said I don't know how I could fix the problem.  sorry for my english :) !

Answer (score 4):

I'm providing an answer to this question just to remove it from the unanswered list.

Your question appears not much clear to me. From the code snippet you posted, my understanding is that you are interested into a **reduction by key with tuple keys**.

Below you can find a full worked example. I hope that it could be helpful to future users.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>

// --- Defining key tuple type
typedef thrust::tuple<int,int> Tuple;

typedef thrust::host_vector<Tuple>::iterator  dIter1;
typedef thrust::host_vector<float>::iterator  dIter2;

/************************************/
/* EQUALITY OPERATOR BETWEEN TUPLES */
/************************************/
struct BinaryPredicate
{
  __host__ __device__ bool operator () 
                      (const Tuple& lhs, const Tuple& rhs) 
  {
    return (thrust::get<0>(lhs) == thrust::get<0>(rhs)) && (thrust::get<1>(lhs) == thrust::get<1>(rhs));
  }
};

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int N = 7;

    thrust::host_vector<Tuple> keys_input(N);
    thrust::host_vector<float> values_input(N);

    int keys1_input[N]          = {1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1};            // input keys 1
    int keys2_input[N]          = {1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 2, 1};            // input keys 2
    float input_values[N]       = {9., 8., 7., 6., 5., 4., 3.};     // input values

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        keys_input[i] = thrust::make_tuple(keys1_input[i], keys2_input[i]);
        values_input[i] = input_values[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%i %i\n", thrust::get<0>(keys_input[i]), thrust::get<1>(keys_input[i]));

    thrust::host_vector<Tuple> keys_output(N);
    thrust::host_vector<float> values_output(N);

    thrust::pair<dIter1, dIter2> new_end;

    new_end = thrust::reduce_by_key(keys_input.begin(), 
                                    keys_input.end(), 
                                    values_input.begin(), 
                                    keys_output.begin(), 
                                    values_output.begin(), 
                                    BinaryPredicate(),
                                    thrust::plus<float>());

    int Nkeys = new_end.first - keys_output.begin();

    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < Nkeys; i++) printf("%i; %f\n", i, values_output[i]);

    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < Nkeys; i++) printf("%i %i\n", thrust::get<0>(keys_output[i]), thrust::get<1>(keys_output[i]));

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

The above worked example referred to `host_vector`'s. Below, a fully worked example considering the case when key and value vectors are regular `cudaMalloc`'ed arrays.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

// --- Defining key tuple type
typedef thrust::tuple<int, int> Tuple;

typedef thrust::device_vector<Tuple>::iterator  dIter1;
typedef thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator  dIter2;

/************************************/
/* EQUALITY OPERATOR BETWEEN TUPLES */
/************************************/
struct BinaryPredicate
{
    __host__ __device__ bool operator ()
        (const Tuple& lhs, const Tuple& rhs)
    {
        return (thrust::get<0>(lhs) == thrust::get<0>(rhs)) && (thrust::get<1>(lhs) == thrust::get<1>(rhs));
    }
};

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int N = 7;

    // --- Keys and input values on the host: allocation and definition
    int h_keys1_input[N] = { 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 };                                         // --- Input keys 1 - host side
    int h_keys2_input[N] = { 1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 2, 1 };                                         // --- Input keys 2 - host side
    float h_input_values[N] = { 9., 8., 7., 6., 5., 4., 3. };                               // --- Input values - host side

    // --- Keys and input values on the device: allocation
    int *d_keys1_input;     gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_keys1_input, N * sizeof(int)));         // --- Input keys 1 - device side
    int *d_keys2_input;     gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_keys2_input, N * sizeof(int)));         // --- Input keys 2 - device side
    float *d_input_values;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_input_values, N * sizeof(float)));      // --- Input values - device side

    // --- Keys and input values: host -> device
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_keys1_input, h_keys1_input,   N * sizeof(int),   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_keys2_input, h_keys2_input,   N * sizeof(int),   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_input_values, h_input_values, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- From raw pointers to device_ptr
    thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr_keys1 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_keys1_input);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr_keys2 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_keys2_input);
    thrust::device_ptr<float> dev_ptr_values = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_input_values);

    // --- Declare outputs
    thrust::device_vector<Tuple> d_keys_output(N);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_values_output(N);

    thrust::pair<dIter1, dIter2> new_end;

    auto begin = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dev_ptr_keys1, dev_ptr_keys2));
    auto end   = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dev_ptr_keys1 + N, dev_ptr_keys2 + N));

    new_end = thrust::reduce_by_key(begin,
                                    end,
                                    dev_ptr_values,
                                    d_keys_output.begin(),
                                    d_values_output.begin(),
                                    BinaryPredicate(),
                                    thrust::plus<float>());

    int Nkeys = new_end.first - d_keys_output.begin();

    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < Nkeys; i++) {
        float output = d_values_output[i];
        printf("%i; %f\n", i, output);
    }

    thrust::host_vector<Tuple> h_keys_output(d_keys_output);
    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < Nkeys; i++) {
        int key1 = thrust::get<0>(h_keys_output[i]);
        int key2 = thrust::get<1>(h_keys_output[i]);
        printf("%i %i\n", key1, key2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```